# A Quick Sudoklu

Tags: sudoku

[image: Sudoklu]

#### Across

```
 1. ?? P on a B B
 2. a S in T S ?
 3. ?? O in a P
 4. as E as ???
 6. ? T on a F
 7. ?? I in a Y
 9. ?? G S
11. ?? H in a D
12. ? B in a B
13. ? S to the W
14. ?? M of F
15. the ? B of M
16. a H Q D N and P is ?? C
17. a S S D has ?? P [or "a S S D has ?? D", or "a S S D has ?? S"]
18. the ? D S
```

#### Down

```
 1. ?? L in the E A
 2. to G the W ? Y
 3. to G B to S ?
 4. a C has ?? E
 5. ?? B K on a P
 6. the ? P of I
 7. ?? P in a G of C
 8. ?? S on a C B
 9. L ? P in a P
10. ?? R in a S of C
12. ? F in a M
13. ? is a C
14. ?? D in a F
15. ?? W in a Y
16. on C ?
18. the ? Y I
```

---

Here is a text only version of the image for any who want one (clue numbers are right aligned while unnumbered unfilled clue squares are `?`):

```
   1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9
 +-------+-------+-------+
A| · · · | · · · | · 1 ? |A
B| · 2 · | · · · | 3 ? · |B
C| · · · | 4 ? 5 | · · · |C
 +-------+-------+-------+
D| · · · | ? · ? | · · 6 |D
E| 7 8 · | · · · | 910 · |E
F|11 ? · | 12· · | · ? · |F
 +-------+-------+-------+
G| · ·13 | ·14 ? | · · · |G
H| ·15 · | · ? · | ·16 ? |H
J| ·17 ? | · · · |18 · · |J
 +-------+-------+-------+
   1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9
```

Comment: Note to others: I assume the letters are abbreviations, for example 15 down might be 52 weeks in a year. But I have nowhere near enough to post as an answer

Comment: @JonathanAllen Would I be right in thinking that there might be at least one "of" or similar little word omitted from 17a for the sake of symmetry?

Comment: (I think I have nearly all of them, but "nearly all of them" is not nearly enough to allow you to deduce many other entries in the sudoku...)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan 17a has no missing word unless there's a wording I haven't thought about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Credit where it's due: Thanks to @Stidgeon and @Reinier for pointing out in comments some answers I hadn't found.)

> Across
>
>   1. ?? P on a B B <-- 24 points on a backgammon board`
>   2. a S in T S ? <-- a stitch in time saves nine
>   3. ?? O in a P <-- 16 ounces in a pound
>   4. as E as ??? <-- as easy as 123
>   6. ? T on a F <-- 5 toes on a foot
>   7. ?? I in a Y <-- 36 inches in a yard
>   9. ?? G S <-- 21 gun salute
>  11. ?? H in a D <-- 24 hours in a day
>  12. ? B in a B <-- 8 bits in a byte
>  13. ? S to the W <-- 3 sheets to the wind
>  14. ?? M of F <-- 15 minutes of fame [*thanks, @Reinier!*]
>  15. the ? B of M <-- 5 books of Moses
>  16. a H Q D N and P is ?? C <-- a half, quarter, dollar, and nickel is 91 cents
>  17. _a S S D has ?? P/D/S <-- a six-sided die has 21 pips, dots, or spots [*thanks to Stidgeon for spotting that we only needed to vary the last word*]
>  18. the ? D S <-- 7 deadly sins
>
>  Down
>
>   1. ?? L in the E A <-- 26 letters in the English alphabet
>   2. to G the W ? Y <-- to go the whole 9 yards
>   3. to G B to S ? <-- to go back to square 1
>   4. a C has ?? E <-- a cube has 12 edges
>   5. ?? B K on a P <-- 36 black keys on a piano
>   6. the ? P of I <-- 5 pillars of Islam
>   7. ?? P in a G of C <-- 32 pieces in a game of chess
>   8. ?? S on a C B <-- 64 squares on a chess board
>   9. L ? P in a P <-- like 2 peas in a pod
>  10. ?? R in a S of C <-- 13 ranks in a suit of cards [*thanks, @Reinier!*]
>  12. ? F in a M <-- 8 furlongs in a mile [thanks, @Stidgeon!]
>  13. ? is a C <-- 3 is a crowd
>  14. ?? D in a F <-- 14 days in a fortnight
>  15. ?? W in a Y <-- 52 weeks in a year
>  16. on C ? <-- on cloud 9
>  18. the ? Y I <-- the 7 year itch

and then the sudoku solves as follows:

> `1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9
>   +-------+-------+-------+
>  A| 1 3 7 | 5 6 9 | 8 2 4 |A
>  B| 5 9 2 | 4 8 7 | 1 6 3 |B
>  C| 6 8 4 | 1 2 3 | 5 7 9 |C
>   +-------+-------+-------+
>  D| 7 1 8 | 2 3 6 | 9 4 5 |D
>  E| 3 6 5 | 9 7 4 | 2 1 8 |E
>  F| 2 4 9 | 8 5 1 | 6 3 7 |F
>   +-------+-------+-------+
>  G| 9 7 3 | 6 1 5 | 4 8 2 |G
>  H| 8 5 6 | 7 4 2 | 3 9 1 |H
>  J| 4 2 1 | 3 9 8 | 7 5 6 |J
>   +-------+-------+-------+
>     1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9`

Minor loose end:

> I haven't figured out all three of the SSD=21 ones. The first is clearly the number of *pips* on a *six-sided die* or a *single standard die*. The second is presumably something like the number of *dominoes* in a *standard set of dominoes* except that that requires an extra "of" which I'm assured isn't needed. And I don't know what the third one is, though I expect that like the other two it's a game-like thing and derived from 1+2+3+4+5+6.

Comment: 17 across: (ROT13) N fvk fvqrq qvr unf 21 cvcf/qbgf/fcbgf

Comment: 12 down is 8 (ROT13) Sheybatf va n zvyr

Comment: You really are nearly there!

Comment: 14a: (ROT13) 15 zvahgrf bs snzr

Comment: 10d: (ROT13) 13 enaxf va n fhvg bs pneqf

Comment: RE the minor loose end: Stidgeon is correct, it's just a word choice (I go with P, but some say D, while others say S).

Comment: Oh, I see -- same SSD every time. Fair enough.